# Excel Macro - Import specific range from Sheet1 from multiple Excel files

Tags: excel, vba, import

I'm trying to import a specific range from Sheet1 from all sheets in a specific folder. I started with this [Loop through all worksheets in all Excel workbooks in a folder to change the font, font size, and alignment of text in all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558767/) but being new to VBA need some help accomplishing the following.

Specifically.

- Import Range("A3:J4") from Sheet1 only in each of the files in the directory. But format it to start in the B column to accommodate:
- Set column A to the filename that each range came from.

  Range(A3:J4) would go to range(B1:K2) for the first file, then range(B3:K4) etc. With the filename for the first file as A1, then the second file A3. Then the list would keep building using this pattern for all files in the folder

  ```
  Sub FormatFiles()
  Const fPath As String = "D:\DataFolder\"
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim sName As String

  With Application
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      .EnableEvents = False
      .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With

  sName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")

  Do Until sName = ""
      With GetObject(fPath & sName)
          For Each sh In .Worksheets
              With sh
                  .Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                  .Cells.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
                  .Cells.Font.Size = 10
              End With
          Next sh
          .Close True
      End With
      sName = Dir
  Loop

  With Application
      .Calculation = xlAutomatic
      .EnableEvents = True
      .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With
  End Sub
  ```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where should the range(A3:J4) from each worksheet go?  Specifically tell us what target range the input ranges from the first and second sheets should be put into. (we can probably figure it out from there)

Comment: range(A3:J4) would go to range(B1:K2) for the first file, then range(B3:K4) etc. With the filename for the first file as A1, then the second file A3. Then the list would keep building using this pattern for all files in the folder.

Comment: Put this in your question.

Comment: I still cannot understand the required input pattern... %) Could you please provide screenshot or any visual example?

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like this?

```
Const fPath As String = "z:\docs\xlfiles\"
Dim sName As String
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim strCopyAddress As String
Dim wb As Workbook

strCopyAddress = "A3:J4"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")
intRow = 1

Do Until sName = ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & sName)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(intRow, 1) = sName
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(strCopyAddress).Copy _
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(intRow, 2)
    wb.Close False

    intRow = intRow + 2
    sName = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```