# vba hides my workbook window, how can i get it to unhide before saving

Tags: excel, vba, window, hide

I copied and edited some code i found in this stackoverflow question:
[Loop through all worksheets in all Excel workbooks in a folder to change the font, font size, and alignment of text in all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558767/loop-through-all-worksheets-in-all-excel-workbooks-in-a-folder-to-change-the-fon)

Although the code does un/protect the sheet (still a work in progress, will eventually be a toggle), when i open the workbooks later the workbook window is hidden and i have to manually press the 'unhide window' icon in the 'view' ribbon. I can't see anything in the code which triggers a 'hide'. Does anyone have any clues how to prevent/workaround this?

my version:

```
    Sub fAMWToggleProtection()

    Const fPath As String = "S:\SHARED\Cidmls\MasterMix Section\Copy of Master Mix templates for testing\"
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sName As String

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    sName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")

    Do Until sName = ""
        With GetObject(fPath & sName)
            For Each sh In .Worksheets
                With sh
                    .Visible = True
                    .Unprotect Password:="icpmr"
'                    .Protect Password:="icpmr"
                End With
            Next sh
'            .Save
'            .Close True

        Debug.Print sName

        End With
        sName = Dir
    Loop

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    MsgBox "Complete", vbOKOnly, "Uprotect all sheets"

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

fAMWToggleProtection_Error:
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in fAMWToggleProtection of Module1"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    With GetObject(fPath & sName)
        .Windows(1).Visible = True ' <-- Not tested, but assuming this is a Workbook object
        For Each sh In .Worksheets
```

Comment: it took me ages to troubleshoot why this was not working for me. in the end i realised that i had not added the period at the beginning! thanks :-)